# Should I increase the PHP memory_limit to match my VM memory_limit?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu

I have a doubt if I should do this or not. I have a VM with 4 GBs RAM from Linode. I want to optimize what I paid for and increase the default value of `memory_limit` in php.ini to allow my Laravel application to take much more than the default value.

```
sed -i -e 's/.*memory_limit.*/memory_limit = 4096M/g' /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini


cat /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini | grep memory_limit


/etc/init.d/php7.1-fpm restart
```

Will this help my Laravel application load faster?

Is there a limit of RAM that PHP will use ? even you set it to 4GB, they will still use a certain amount of RAM like .5 GB? Is it a myth or true ?

Comment: Allowing more memory will not make it faster unless you are using more than allotted. How many concurrent connections are there? Can't use all 4GB twice at the same time. If the application is slow it's unlikely memory is the issue. PHP will use as much as it needs up to the total allotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most of the use cases, no you shouldn't.

By design, PHP scripts doesn't holds state. With an oversimplification here, that means: for each connection (request to the server) a new process with empty memory space will be started.

If you need full 4GB for each request to your application, boy.. you're in big trouble!

You can read more about it, on this article: https://haydenjames.io/understanding-php-memory_limit/